# XAML button content changing based on VB variable

Tags: vb.net, xaml, button

Beginner here. I want to create a button in XAML which has text based on a variable in VB. I have the variable set in VB with

Dim ButtonName1 = "Test"

What will I need to do to make the button content display ButtonName1?

Answer (score 1):

It is really quite easy. Your Button has a Name Property that you can use to reference it in your code behind, note in this example it is `Button1` you just need to assign your string to the Button's Content Property

**Xaml**

```
<Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
```

**xaml.vb**

```
Dim ButtonName1 = "Test"
Button1.Content = ButtonName1
```